# Ubuntu with GTX1080

Tags: nvidia, desktop-background, taskbar

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 with GTX1080.

I have installed nvidia display driver. But I can only see wallpaper without taskbar.

And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't work, so I couldn't reinstall driver.

Comment: As of this artivle it seems you need nvidia-367.18 to make run: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/GTX-1080-CUDA-performance-on-Linux-Ubuntu-16-04-preliminary-results-nbody-and-NAMD-803/

Comment: Which version of nvidia driver did you install ? The latest is nvidia-370